# STM32 elegant way to parse NMEA sentences without allocating to much memory

Tags: c, parsing, stm32, uart, nmea

I'm writing a parser for NMEA sentences.
They can look like this:

```
$GPBWC,220516,5130.02,N,00046.34,W,213.8,T,218.0,M,0004.6,N,EGLM*11
$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62
$GPVTG,360.0,T,348.7,M,000.0,N,000.0,K*43
```

This block of code repeats around each second. I would like to analyze line by line. I use the STM32 Hal UART command to read this. First I use `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` to generate an interrupt when an incoming sentence begins with `$`. Then I parse the first line. By reading `char` by `char` in string until the break line command `\n` is reached. So in this example I parse the first command `$GPBWC`. When I'm done I want to parse the next line `$GPRMS`. However during the parsing of `$GPBWC`  UART doesn't stop and I'm missing the sentences `$GPRMC` and `$GPVTG`.

I can receive the whole block at a time but this requires a lot of allocated memory which is constantly blocked and makes my code unnecessary heavy. Also I need to extend the memory even more if I will have more types of sentences.

I want to get all sentences line by line without missing any of them. There has to be a more elegant way then receiving the whole block at a time.

**Update**

Thx @0___________ for the hint.

I'm implemented the following code:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    update(rx_byte[0]);
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&hlpuart1, rx_byte, 1);
}

void update(char c) {

    if (c == '$') {
        sen_index = 0;
        msgValid = 1;
    }
    
    if (msgValid == 1) {
        sentense[sen_index] = c;
        sen_index++;

        if (c == '\n') {
    
            msgValid = 0;
            strncpy(prefix, sentense + 1, 5);
    
            if (strcmp(prefix, "GPRMC") == 0) {
                ...
            }
    
            if (strcmp(prefix, "GPBWC") == 0) {
                ...
            }
    
            if (strcmp(prefix, "GPVTG") == 0) {
                ...
            }
        }
        ...

    while (1) {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&hlpuart1, rx_byte, 1);
    }
```

This is not the best code but it works.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: parse char by char. Do not wait for the whole line. You need only 1 char buffer for parsing those messages.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Use an existing parser. Also, NMEA has max line length of 82 chacters. `owever during the parsing of $GPBWC UART doesn't stop and I'm missing the sentences` Implement bigger FIFO buffer. At least double buffering, so you can pars and receive. Do not parse in interrupt. `the whole block at a time but this requires a lot of allocated memory which is constantly blocked` I do not understand that. No, you can append from one side constantly while also reading from the other side.

Comment: Interleaving receiving and parsing is the exact opposite of layering and modularity. It's worse than "*not best*", and is low-quality code.

Comment: @KamilCuk the problem is, that the GPS module I have, fire 5 sentenses in a short period of time. if I parse not quick enough I miss sentence No. 2 or 3. Hence I can allocate all 5 sentence at a time and parse them later or I can do as I post it there. I'm still in search of of a better parser. This works ok for my current prototype.

Comment: @sawdust if its so bad, tell me how to do better. You didn't contribute any answer.

Comment: `the problem is` The problem is, you are parsing in an interrupt handler, hence your interrupt is blocked when new characters are transmitted. You have to parse in main loop, and only receive characters in interrupt handler.

Comment: The salient points for a reasonable solution are already posted by @KamilCuk: (1) keep interrupt handling short, simple, & fast; (2) use a circular buffer (aka FIFO) to pass the received data to a processing thread (for parsing plus whatever). "*the problem is ...  if I parse not quick enough ...*" -- We can't evaluate code never posted.

Answer (score 2):

- Do not do much work in interrupt handler! Interrupt handler only reads characters and adds to a buffer. Keep interrupts short & fast.
- FIFO. Interrupt handler appends characters to a FIFO from one side. Then the main loop reads from the fifo from the other side. Remember about volatile and locking needed for communication between interrupt and other code.
- Max NMEA line has 82 characters. Have a static 83 buffer to store a single line *for parser* to parse. Note this is *not* the size of the buffer, only internal NMEA parser buffer for one message.
- Do not reinvent the wheel - NMEA is old, there are millions libraries to parse it. Minmea is a fine library for parsing NMEA messages.
- You may want for faster transfer use DMA, however it is really hard to implement, because you can't depend on interrupt every character. I think only consider DMA if your baudrate is greater than 115200 (or you need really low power consumption).

Comment: I will have a look to Minnmea. Looks promising!